# Django: Reverse for 'wall' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django, django-views

Tried to filter posts by username and it raises `NoReverseMatch`.
I thought it was because of regex in urls but it actually gets the object and works perfectly fine.

## Urls.py

```
url(r'^u/(?P<username>[\w.@-_]+)/$', views.wall, name="wall")
```

## Views.py

```
def wall(request, username):
    post_list = Post.objects.active(username)
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        post_list = Post.objects.all().filter(user__username=username).order_by("-date_created")
    query = request.GET.get("title")

    if query:
        post_list = post_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(text__icontains=query)  # |
            # Q(user__username__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 3)  # 3 Posts per page
    page_name = 'page'
    page = request.GET.get(page_name)
    try:
        post_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        post_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        post_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    for i in post_list:  # Checking if it actually filters by username
        print (i.text)
    print (page_name) # It does
    print (page)
    print (paginator)
    context = {
        "posts": post_list,
        "page_name": page_name,
        "paginator": paginator,
        "page": page,
    }
    return render(request, "post_list.html", context)
```

Comment: The error happens when you call `reverse('wall', ...)` or `{% url 'wall' ... %}` somewhere. The `wall` view doesn't cause the error.

Comment: @C14L That's the answer. Thanks!